# Ordered a new laptop; it came with a stuck red pixel. Can it be fixed?

Tags: stuck-pixel

I ordered a new laptop and it came with a stuck pixel. It's a red one, so I think it can be fixed. Although, the methods don't seem to be permanently fixing it. I'm using a program, UDPixel, and it makes the pixel less apparent, but after the screen turns off for a while, it comes back.

I tried pressure, but that doesn't seem to work either. I contacted the company and according to their manufacturer's warranty, 5 or more pixels need to be present for them to fix it. Am I out of luck or should I be persistent?

Comment: Most sellers of laptops have a return grace period where you can return it for a full refund for any reason, who did you buy it from?

Comment: Indeed there's a grace period. Don't want to return it though. I'll have to deal with it I guess.